# Do I need all these wraps?

Tags: html, css

I was thinking it might be possible just to have one wrap, rather than a seperate one on the header and footer as well.

Can this be done, can I have a single wrap container that puts the content in the middle at a fixed width on all elements?

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/HMsKa/

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <link href="/static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container-wrap">
            <div id="header-wrap" class="full_width">
                <div id="header-container" class="dc1">
                    <div id="header" class="thin_width rel">
                        <a href="/"><img src="/static/img/header.jpg" id="logo" alt="coming soon" title="coming soon"></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/posts/list/">Link1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/posts/create/">Link 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/about">Link 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="container" class="thin_width">
                <div class="full_width" style="height:auto;">
                    <div id="col-main">                
        <h1>Sed ut perspiciatis unde</h1>
            <div id="fullwidth">
                <form id="searchForm" action="/search">
                        <input type="text" name="kw" class="field r2 lft dc1 tc5 b1 ts3" id="field_regular" placeholder="Keyword">
                        <input type="text" name="loc" class="field r2 lft dc1 tc5 b1 ts3" id="field_regular" placeholder="Location">
                        <input type="submit" class="button r2 b1 ts3" id="button_search" value="Search">
                </form>
            </div>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatne voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
     </div>
               </div>                    
            </div>

            <div id="footer-wrap" class="thin_width">
                <div id="footer-container" class="full_width abs dc1">
                    <div id="footer" class="thin_width rel">
                    &#169; 2012 Company, Inc.
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/faq">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/terms">Terms</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/privacy">Privacy</a></li>
                    </ul>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>​
```

**Here is the CSS:**

```
/* GENERAL */
html { height:100%; }
body { height:100%; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; font-size:100%; }
p { font size: 13px; margin: 10px 0; padding: 0; }
h1 { font-size: 22px; }  
h2 { font-size: 17px; }  
h3 { font-size: 14px; } 
blockquote { font-style: italic; }

/*POSITIONING */
.lft { float: left; }
.rgt { float: right; }
.rel { position: relative; }
.abs { position: absolute; }

/* TEXT COLOURS */
.tc6 { color: #4C4C4C; }
.tc5 { color: #333333; }
.tc4 { color: #999999; }
.tc3 { color: #808080; }
.tc2 { color: #F5F5F5; }
.tc1 { color: #FFFFFF; }

/* TEXT STYLING */
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
.italic { font-style:italic; }

/* TEXT SIZES */
.ts5 { font-size: 21px; }
.ts4 { font-size: 18px; }
.ts3 { font-size: 15px; }
.ts2 { font-size: 13px; }
.ts1 { font-size: 11px; }

/* DIV COLOURS */
.dc6 { background-color: #4C4C4C; }
.dc5 { background-color: #333333; }
.dc4 { background-color: #999999; }
.dc3 { background-color: #808080; }
.dc2 { background-color: #F5F5F5; }
.dc1 { background-color: #FFFFFF; }

/* WIDTHS */
.full_width { width: 100%; }
.thin_width { width: 940px; }

/* BORDERS */
.b1 { border: 1px solid; }

/* RADIUS */
.r6 { border-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; }
.r2 { border-radius: 2px; -moz-border-radius: 2px; -webkit-border-radius: 2px; }

/* FIELD */
.field { line-height:27px; font-family:arial, sans-serif; border-color: #d9d9d9; border-top:solid 1px #c0c0c0; padding-left:5px; margin-right: 15px; width:250px; }

/* BUTTON */
.button  { cursor:pointer; font-family: arial, sans-serif; min-width: 70px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; color: white; }
.button:hover { border: 1px solid #2F5BB7; }
.button:active { -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #888; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #888; box-shadow: 0 0 2px #888; }

/* BUTTONS */
#button_search { height: 34px; background: url(http://www.divology.com/wp-content/themes/divology/tutorials/google-search/ico-search.png) no-repeat #4d90fe center; border: 1px solid #3079ED; text-indent:-999px; color: transparent; line-height:0; font-size:0; }
#button_primary { border-color: #3079ED; background-color: #55A4F2; }
#button_secondary { border-color: gray; }
#field_regular { height:27px; }

/* FIELDS */
#field_large { height:300px; }

/* HEADER */
#header-wrap { top: 0; left: 0; }
#header-container { line-height: 60px; height: 60px; border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5; }
#header { margin: 0 auto; position: relative; }
#header h1 { color: #beffbf; text-align: left; width: 290px; margin: 0; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 20px; }
#header h1 em { color: #90b874; font-size: small; display: block; }
#header ul { top:0; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; position: absolute; right: 0; }
#header ul li { float: left; margin-right: 5px; }
#header ul li a{ color: #90b874; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.4em; margin-right: 5px; text-decoration: none; }
#header ul li a:hover { color: #beffbf;  }

/* CONTAINER */
#container { margin: 0 auto; font-size: 1.4em; overflow: auto; padding: 31px 0 80px 0px; }
#container-wrap { min-height:100%; position:relative; min-width: 940px; }
#logo { height:20px; }

/* FOOTER */
#footer-wrap { bottom: 0; left: 0; }
#footer-container { line-height: 60px; height: 60px; bottom: 0; border-top: 1px solid #E5E5E5; }
#footer { margin: 0 auto; position: relative; }
#footer ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; }
#footer ul li { float: left; margin-right: 5px; }
#footer ul li a { color: #90b874; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; text-decoration: none; }
#footer ul li a:hover { color: #beffbf;  }

#faq EM { display:none; }
#faq LI STRONG { font-weight:normal; color:#246; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer; }

.hidden { display:none; }

#content{
    background: orange;
    height: auto;
}

#col-main { overflow:hidden;  }
```

Any input would be much appreciated! Thank you.

​

Comment: No, you really, really do not need all those divs. I've updated your html to the bare minimum. See if you can update the CSS yourself. If not I'll see it here, and I'll help you on your way.
http://jsfiddle.net/HMsKa/6/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The trouble is the footer is no longer docked to the bottom. Am I right in thinking that all these additional tags are required just for that effect?

Comment: not really. Because if your screen would be higher, it would still not dock to the bottom. more to come, jsut a sec

Comment: You could position the footer to the bottom with position:fixed; bottom: 0;
I would advise you to read up on CSS, because this is actually pretty basic stuff.

Comment: This isnt the same result im afraid. On my version, the footer is forced down off the page when there is enough content. On your version  the footer isnt forced down, it sits on the bottom. Its quite a unique and specific layout but is quite complex unfortunately.  http://jsfiddle.net/HMsKa/9/

Comment: OK, this should be possible. let me think about it.

Comment: Got it.
With just a little content: http://jsfiddle.net/HMsKa/10/
With more content then the page is high: http://jsfiddle.net/HMsKa/12/

I haven't tested it thoroughly so you should still do that. And you maight want to use the "min height fast hack" for the min-height piece (http://www.dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll put it in an answer so you can upvote and accept ;-)

Got it.

With just a little content: http://jsfiddle.net/HMsKa/10

With more content then the page is high: http://jsfiddle.net/HMsKa/12

I haven't tested it thoroughly so you should still do that. And you might want to use the "min height fast hack" for the min-height piece (dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack).

Comment: Thank you for the help. Ive made some tweaks and I have got this. Two questions though. Is it not better to have a single width wrap that covers the header, footer and middle content and sets its width to 600px? At the moment,we set each to "thin_width". Secondly, how do you centralise the content? Something to do with margin:0; but I cant figure it out . http://jsfiddle.net/HMsKa/18/

Comment: I did that with #container. you can set a margin: 0 auto on it, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HMsKa/21/

Comment: "And I love you, random citizen"